# No entiendo Relaciones en poo

Tags: java, poo, uml, relaciones

estoy intentando realizar un proyecto de poo pero al pasar relaciones de uml a codigo se me dificulta mucho,me gustaría que alguien me ayudara con una explicación,dejo imagen del proyecto gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El diagrama de clases aporta una visión de estructura de un sistema sin mostrar la naturaleza dinámica. Cada caja se divide en 3 partes horizontales.

- La parte superior contiene el nombre de la clase.
- La sección media menciona sus atributos
- La tercera sección contiene las operaciones o comportamientos de la clase.

Los diagramas de clase también pueden mostrar relaciones entre clases.
La multiplicidad de un extremo de una asociación significa el número de objetos de dicha clase que se asocia con la otra clase.

En la experiencia que lleve al traducir uml a codigo no siempre se corresponden ya que los diagramas fueron diseñados para abstraer el sistema en un lenguaje de modelado que todos pudieran comprender, seguir, observar; pero no esta exento de hacerlo te daré un ejemplo de como tratar y seguir al pie con el diseño:

```
package javaexamples;

public class producto
{
    private String codigo;
    private int unidadesDisponibles;
    private Double precio;

    public producto(String codigo, int unidadesDisponibles, Double precio)
    {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.unidadesDisponibles = unidadesDisponibles;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String alta()
    {
        // codigo para insertar a la base de datos      
    }

    public void baja()
    {
        // codigo para dar de baja el producto a la base de datos       
    }

    public String modificacion()
    {
        // codigo para modificar en la base de datos        
    }

    //Otros metodos que puedes incluir
}
```

Fragmento de codigo basado en la clase producto diseñado en UML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado un exito en tu desarrollo